# How Many CUs are used by ComputeBudgetProgram?

Tags: compute-budget

I am using the `ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitLimit` & `ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitPrice` instructions to reduce the CU budget for a small transfer transaction and increase the PriorityFee.

I presume I need to request enough of a budget for the two ComputeBudgetProgram instructions themselves. How many CUs are consumed for each?

Answer (score 4):

Edit: 150 CUs are consumed by the ComputeBudget program, per https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/a36e1b211d144f3cf0f2a6f68da7600b49454c1a/runtime/src/block_cost_limits.rs#L45

It will also fail on duplicates to avoid someone spamming with transactions that only use the ComputeBudget program.

You can see the reference code: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/ca115594ff61086d67b4fec8977f5762e526a457/program-runtime/src/compute_budget.rs#L151-L242

Comment: There could be add some cost of the execution of the `ComputeBudget` program by default in future: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/pull/29795